# both coverity and purify complain but I cannot figure out: how to use stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

both coverify and purify complain there are memory problems. Can someone shred some light ?

```
int main()
{
    int count=123;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<< "123_"<< count << "_" << ".log";
    const char * filename=ss.str().c_str();
    std::cout << filename << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The string returned by `ss.str()` is a temporary, and is destroyed at the end of the full expression the `;`.  Leaving you with a dangling pointer in `filename`.

Comment: I see. So what's the correct usage ? I need to copy it over to another string ? thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: as of C++11, file streams can be opened with a `std::string` containing the filename. You may not have to get a `char*` at all.

Comment: thanks both of you. Now I understand the problem and how to fix it.